# Adding a background color for navigation items built from slices

Tags: html, css, navigation, background-image, slice

I am designing a custom navigation menu, which you can see in it's current state [here](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/test2/). Each individual navigation item looks like this:

[image: navigation item]

So essentially each nav item 'hangs' from a horizontal bar. The main part of the image is made up of three slices of an image:

Left: [image]   Right: [image] and middle: [image]

The background for the middle DIV has repeat-x applied, so that it will grow to fit the content of the navigation items, i.e. the text.

This is the CSS I currently have for the left, right and middle DIVs:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 13px;
    background-image: url(nav/images/nav_01.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:46px;
    margin-left:2%;
}

.middle {
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(nav/images/nav_02.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Typewriter;
    color:#393526;
    height:46px;
    padding-left:1px;
}

.right {
    float: left;
    width: 13px;
    background-image: url(nav/images/nav_03.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:46px;
}
```

So far so good, but I then had to work out how to include the vertical bar that joins the main horizontal bar to the image constructed for the nav items, so that it was always centred.  The way I did it was to include a div for it within the middle div as follows:

```
<li>
<div class="nav_image">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="middle"><div class="top"></div>home</div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
</li>
```

and then apply a negative margin-top to the 'top' DIV:

```
.top {
    height:27px;
    background-image: url(nav/images/top.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    margin-top:-24px;
}
```

and a positive margin-top to the 'nav_image' DIV:

```
.nav_image {
    margin-top:27px;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve what I am looking for, but it is working so far.

The issue I am having is setting a background color for the 'nav_image' DIV.  I would like to set a color for this, and another color on hover.  I was hoping that I could add rounded corners to this DIV and then set a background color for this that would show behind the background image.

At the moment the DIV 'nav_image' is showing a width of 1200px and a height of 0px though.  I would have thought it would have inherited the total width of the three child DIVS, i.e. left, middle and right, but clearly this is not what is happening.  So I don't seem to have a DIV to apply the background color to.

I hope this is clear, thanks for reading, and I'd be glad to get any advice on this.

Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) add these to the css:

```
ul#list-nav li {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

2) add `<div class="clear"></div>` after each `<div class="right"></div>`

3) remove `.left`'s `margin-left: 2%;` (add margin to `ul#list-nav li` instead)

the `nav_image` should have correct width and height now

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. By adding your code and some margins to the left, right, middle and top divs, I managed to get the effect I was looking for.  I have now amended the code for the page some more, so that the hover effect on the background image is only triggered when hovering over the lower part of the nav item.  You can see the latest page [here](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/test2/index.html). I am wondering if you have any ideas about simplifying the markup for each nav item, as suggested by j-man86 below.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you should like this I check to your code and some modify and created easily code to your navi and logo Please Checked'

**Css**

```
.header, .navi, ul, li, a, span{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
    .header{
        overflow:hidden;
        z-index:5;    }


        .logo{
            position:relative;
            z-index:1;
    height:188px;
    width:100%;
        }


        .navi{
            position:absolute;
            left:40%;
            right:0;
            z-index:2;
            top:148px;
            list-style:none;
        }


        li{
            float:left;
            background:url('http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/test2/nav/images/top.png') no-repeat 10% 0;
            margin-left:2%;
        }
        .navi a{
            background:url('http://s16.postimage.org/yqxo6bq6p/navi_left.png') no-repeat left top;
            padding-left:9px;
            color:#000;
            margin-top:27px;
            text-decoration:none;
            font-size:22px;
            float:left;
                border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
        }
        .navi a span{
            background:url('http://s17.postimage.org/ukpot5zcb/navi_right.png') no-repeat right top;
            padding-right:9px;
            float:left;
            line-height:38px;
            border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
        }
        .navi a:hover span, .navi a:hover{
            background:green;
            color:#fff;
            border-radius:5px;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
        <img src="http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/test2/logo.png" alt="" class="logo" />
        <ul class="navi">
            <li><a href="#"><span>home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>news</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>forums</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>articles</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Live demo here  http://jsfiddle.net/Kj2e9/

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the markup alot to start.

```
<li>
    <a>
         Home
    </a>
</li>
```

Then I would use pseudo elements rather than straight HTML markup to achieve the "side images". I haven't tested this, but it should point you in the right direction:

The key additions here are: 1) Use absolute positioning on the :before and :after pseudos and 2) Add 13px right and left padding to the `<a>` element. Other than that, your code looks about right and 3) display: block on the `<a>` i think is probably important in getting this to work right

```
li a {
    padding: 0 13px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(nav/images/nav_02.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Typewriter;
    color:#393526;
    height:46px;
    padding-left:1px;
}

li a:before,
li a:after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 13px;
    height:46px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}

li a:before {
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(nav/images/nav_03.png);
}

li a:after {
    right: 0;
    background-image: url(nav/images/nav_01.png);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I like the idea of simpler markup.  I have implemented your code on a test page [here](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/test2/test.html).  The pseudo elements and the main element are overlapping though.  Also I have the issue of the background-color running over the edge of the images on hover.  Finally, what would the best way of including the vertical image that links the main bar to the nav item be with your method?  I have the original page working with the more complicated markup [here](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/test2/index.html), so you can see what I am aiming for.